# how to get dataset by condition list and order by time

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

Background: Springboot with mybatis mapper.xml to write sql .
I have a db table like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id|  data_no| data_name | created_time        |value|
--------------------------------------------------------
1 |  a1      |  weight   | 2019-07-24 13:30:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
2 |  b1      |  height   | 2019-07-24 13:31:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
3 |   a2     |  weight   | 2019-07-24 13:33:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
4 |  c1      |  height   | 2019-07-24 13:32:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
5 |  a1      |  weight   | 2019-07-24 13:35:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
6 |  a1      |  length   | 2019-07-24 14:30:57 |100  |
--------------------------------------------------------
7 |  b1      |  height   | 2019-07-24 15:30:57 |100  |
```

Now I have a list of `data_no`  and a list of `data_name`.I want to get a list of data result which for one `data_no`& `data_name` only get one record order by the latest created_time .eg:

```
List<String> dataNos :{a1,b1}
List<String>dataNames :{weight,height}

result:
[
   {a1,weight,2019-07-24 13:35:57,100}, 
   {b1,height,2019-07-24 15:30:57,100}
]
```

how can i write the mybatis mapper ?

i don't know how to do this by one mybatis expression, now i get a list with duplicate data(same data_no& data_name with many created_time), and filter created_time in java code .but if too many datas.it cost time.
a Query Bean like:

```
`public class QueryModel{
    private List<String> dataNo;
    private List<String> dataName;
}`
```

result model:

```
public class ResultModel{
    private List<DataModel> result;
}
public class DataModel{
    private dataNo;
    private dataName;
    private Date createdTime;
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: I will help you with ibatis mapping. before that can you please show me your query

Comment: @VinayHegde . now query is like this:<select parameterType="QueryModel">
 select from table
 data_no as dataNo,
 data_name as dataName,
 created_time as createdtime,
 value as value
 <where>
  AND data_no in
                <foreach collection="dataNos" open="(" close=")" separator="," item="item">
                    #{item}
                </foreach>
  AND data_name in
                <foreach collection="dataNames" open="(" close=")" separator="," item="item">
                    #{item}
                </foreach>
 </where>
</select>

Comment: Not like that , Add a plane SQL query in post.

Comment: @VinayHegde sorry,i don't know how to write plane sql query

Comment: plane sql means the query you will execute in mysql workbench.

Comment: @VinayHegde sorry i don't know how to write sql statement neither.sql&mybatis are both hard to me now

Comment: without sql its difficult to solve still you can check here : http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html